# Equivalent plpgsql trigger in C

Tags: c, postgresql, triggers

I've a PostgreSQL 9.0 server and I'm using heritage on some tables, for this reason I have to simulate foreign keys through triggers like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION othertable_before_update_trigger()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  sql   VARCHAR;
  rows  SMALLINT;
BEGIN
  IF (NEW.parenttable_id IS DISTINCT FROM OLD.parenttable_id) THEN
    sql  := 'SELECT id '
         || 'FROM parentTable '
         || 'WHERE id = ' || NEW.parenttable_id || ';';
     BEGIN
        EXECUTE sql;
        GET DIAGNOSTICS rows = ROW_COUNT;

     EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
           RAISE EXCEPTION 'Error when I try find in parentTable the id %. SQL: %. ERROR: %',
                            NEW.parenttable_id,sql,SQLERRM;
     END;

     IF rows = 0 THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Not found a row in parentTable with id %. SQL: %.',NEW.parenttable_id,sql;
     END IF;
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But due to performance I try to create a equivalent trigger in C code:

```
#include "postgres.h"
#include "executor/spi.h"       /* this is what you need to work with SPI */
#include "commands/trigger.h"   /* ... and triggers */

#ifdef PG_MODULE_MAGIC
PG_MODULE_MAGIC;
#endif
extern Datum othertable_before_update_trigger(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS);

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(othertable_before_update_trigger);

Datum
 othertable_before_update_trigger(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS) {

   TriggerData *trigdata = (TriggerData *) fcinfo->context;
   TupleDesc   tupdesc;
   HeapTuple   rettuple;
   bool        isnull;
   int         ret, i;

   /* make sure it's called as a trigger at all */
   if (!CALLED_AS_TRIGGER(fcinfo))
     elog(ERROR, "othertable_before_update_trigger: not called by trigger manager");

   /* tuple to return to executor */
   if (TRIGGER_FIRED_BY_UPDATE(trigdata->tg_event))
     rettuple = trigdata->tg_newtuple;
   else
     rettuple = trigdata->tg_trigtuple;

   tupdesc = trigdata->tg_relation->rd_att;

   /* connect to SPI manager */
   if ((ret = SPI_connect()) < 0)
     elog(ERROR, "othertable_before_update_trigger (fired %s): SPI_connect returned %d", "before", ret);

   [A]

   [B]

   return PointerGetDatum(rettuple);
 }
```

I need fill the code in:

1. **[A]**: get the previous and new values for **parenttable_id**. With:

   int32 att = DatumGetInt32(heap_getattr(rettuple, 1, tupdesc, &isnull));

   or

   int32 att = DatumGetInt32(SPI_getbinval(rettuple, tupdesc, 1, &isnull));

I can get only the old value of **parenttable_id** but not the new value. Even if I try to use the column name instead of their number with:

```
GetAttributeByName (rettuple->t_data, "parenttable_id", &isnull);
```

Getting error: *record type has not been registered*

1. **[B]**: execute the query **SELECT id FROM parentTable WHERE id = NEW.parenttable_id**

I found the function **SPI_execute_with_args**, but I haven't found examples of this for my case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This does not strike me as the sort of trigger that will benefit from moving to C.  You can take advantage of a lot of caching of plans in pl/pgsql and this is likely to help more than moving to C will speed things up.  Additionally there are two big performance red flags here that strike me as worth fixing.

The first is that EXCEPTION blocks have significant performance costs.  All you are doing here is reporting an exception in more friendly terms.  You would do better to just remove it if performance is an issue.

The second is your EXECUTE which means that the query plan will never be cached.  You really should change this to a straight query.

When you combine this with the possibility of a C-language trigger causing crashes or worse in the back-end, I think you will be putting a lot of effort into rewriting the trigger for fewer performance gains than you could get by rewriting it in pl/pgsql.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When you said, *"The second is your EXECUTE [...] You really should change this to a straight query"*. The question is, how I can do it in this case?

Comment: You have two options.  You could `SELECT count(*) INTO rows ....` or you could `PERFORM * FROM ...` and then get diagnostics.

Comment: Sorry for my insistence, but how i can translate the query of `sql variable` in the psql function to `straight query`? I don't want to know how many rows has the table, only if register with `id = NEW.parenttable_id` exists.