# Inheritance and Relationship in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, inheritance, relationship

I have some problems with SQL-code.

Sequences and tables creation, some data inserting in:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE tmp_id_places START 1;
CREATE SEQUENCE tmp_id_books START 1;

CREATE TABLE tmp_places (
  id int PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT nextval('tmp_id_places'),
  name text
);

CREATE TABLE tmp_cities (population int) INHERITS (tmp_places);
CREATE TABLE tmp_rivers (lenght int) INHERITS (tmp_places);

INSERT INTO tmp_cities (name, population) VALUES
  ('Moscow', 15),
  ('St. Petersburg', 9);

INSERT INTO tmp_rivers (name, lenght) VALUES
  ('Volga', 115),
  ('Angara', 319);

CREATE TABLE tmp_books (
  id int PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT nextval('tmp_id_books'),
  id_place int REFERENCES tmp_places(id),
  title text
);
```

Вut this code make an error:

```
INSERT INTO tmp_books (title, id_place) VALUES
  ('Some book about Moscow', 1),
  ('Another book about Angara', 4);
```

Table **tmp_books** contain information about places. But I can't insert data in it, because there aren't any data in master-table **tmp_places** (all data in child-tables).

So can this  been resolved anyway?

Answer (score 4):

Take a closer look at [this section](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-inherit.html) in the PostrgeSQL docs. If you will insert data into the child table, then data will be found *only* in the child table. On the other hand, inserting into the master table makes new rows visible in all the child tables also. So you have to *always* work on the master tables at first hand.

I've been working with inheritance a while ago and also faced the same problem.
I ended up with the following:

1. `INSERT` a new entry into the `tmp_places`;
2. `UPDATE` extra fields, say, in `tmp_cities` with their respective values.

Back in 7.4 times I had to create a set of functions for such activities.
Now it is possible to use the [`RETURNING` clause of `INSERT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-insert.html) statement and [CTEs with `UPDATE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html) (also on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/cf0f9/3)):

```
WITH theid AS (
  INSERT INTO tmp_places (name) VALUES ('Moscow') RETURNING id
)
UPDATE tmp_cities tc SET population = 15
  FROM theid
 WHERE tc.id = theid.id;
```

You should also be careful with constraints, as not all of them are inherited.

Answer (score 2):

Denis,

Inheritance does not propagate in INSERT and COPY statements in Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

In PostgreSQL you shouldn't create a foreign key to parent table because, as you just find out, this table acts almost as a view instead of a table (since actual data are in their respective children). For now only be solved by triggers.

You can see an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110559/equivalent-plpgsql-trigger-in-c) of this "type of triggers".